# How to write this decorator?

Tags: python

HELP Please . How Write This Decorator (Take a validator if the validator return "True" send args to func :

```
#define decorator here ...

def validator(x):
    return x>=0

@decorator(validator)
def f(x):
    return x**0.5

print(f(4)) #should print 2
print(f(-4)) #should print error
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question.  What have you tried? Please see [ask].

Comment: How? Write Please

Comment: Asking twice doesn't help [How to use validator in decorate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056841/how-to-use-validator-in-decorate)

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
def validator(func):
   def is_positive(x):
      assert x>=0, "function {} wont work because x is negative".format(func.__name__)
      return func(x)
   return is_positive

@validator
def f(x):
    return x**0.5

print(f(4)) #should print 2
print(f(-4)) #should print error
```

Outputs:

```
2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
Exception: function f wont work because x is negative
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the decorator definition

```
def decorator(method):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner_wrapper(x):
            if method(x):
                return func(x)
            else:
                raise Exception
        return inner_wrapper
    return wrapper


def is_positiv(x):
    return x > 0


@decorator(is_positiv)
def f(x):
    return x**0.5
```

Here is some documentation about decorator in python (https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Best regard